# Rich Text field Inline Editing on Datatable - Unable to Save changes

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm fairly new to LWC, I have managed to build a datatable and using custom types to display rich text content however I'm unable to edit and save rich text content when I use:
lightning-input-rich-text tag in the richTextColumnTypeEditable.html file

If I use:
lightning-input tag
this will work fine as an alternative however in the edit mode you can only edit in small box and it shows you the html tags as well which is not ideal for an end user.

Everytime I select the edit and enter a character the following error keeps appearing while using the:
lightning-input-rich-text
any idea what this is?
Also once the editor window opens clicking off it does not close it.

[image]

Technical Stuff Error:

[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
a()@https://static.lightning.force.com/.../auraFW/javascript/tr2UlkrAHzi37ijzEeD2UA/aura_prod.js:1000:112
{anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/.../auraFW/javascript/tr2UlkrAHzi37ijzEeD2UA/aura_prod.js:1000:305
dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/.../auraFW/javascript/tr2UlkrAHzi37ijzEeD2UA/aura_prod.js:13:46387
B.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/.../auraFW/javascript/tr2UlkrAHzi37ijzEeD2UA/aura_prod.js:13:13839
B.triggerEditFinished()@https://redacted--redacted.sandbox.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/primitiveDatatableIeditPanel.js:1:6220
B.handlePanelLostFocus()@https://redacted--redacted.sandbox.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/primitiveDatatableIeditPanel.js:1:5480
eval()@https://redacted--redacted.sandbox.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/primitiveDatatableIeditPanel.js:1:6381

myCustomDatatable.js:

[image]

```
import LightningDatatable from "lightning/datatable";


import richTextColumnType from "./richTextColumnType.html";


import richTextColumnTypeEditable from "./richTextColumnTypeEditable.html";


import customNumberTemplate from './customNumber.html';


import customNumberEditTemplate from './customNumberEdit.html';


export default class MyCustomDatatable extends LightningDatatable {

static customTypes={
    // custom type definition
    richText: {
        template: richTextColumnType,
        editTemplate: richTextColumnTypeEditable,
        standardCellLayout: true,
    },
    customNumber: {
        template: customNumberTemplate,
        editTemplate: customNumberEditTemplate,
        standardCellLayout: true,
        typeAttributes: ['status', 'min'],
    }
}
}
```

richTextColumnType.html:

[image]

```
<template if:true={wrapText}>
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={value} class="slds-truncate">
    </lightning-formatted-rich-text>
</template>
<template if:false={wrapText}>
    <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={value}>
    </lightning-formatted-rich-text>
</template>
```

richTextColumnTypeEditable.html:

[image]

```
<lightning-input-rich-text
    data-inputable="true"
    value={editedValue}>
</lightning-input-rich-text>
```

HTML Code which displays the datatable:

[image]

```
        <div class="slds-size_2-of-3 slds-align_absolute-center slds-p-bottom_small">
        <c-my-custom-datatable
        key-field="Id"
        columns={columnsRich}
        data={tableData}
        wrap-text-max-lines="3">
        </c-my-custom-datatable>
    </div>
```

JS content of the main LWC to build table:
[image]

```
columnsRich = [
    // standard text column
    { label: "Text Column", fieldName: "textCol", wrapText: true, editable: true },
    { label: "Number Column", fieldName: "numberCol", type: 'customNumber', wrapText: true, editable: true,
        typeAttributes: {
        status: {fieldName: 'status'},
        min: 0 },
        cellAttributes: {
        class: 'slds-theme_alert-texture'
        }
    },
    // custom richText column
    { label: "Rich Text", fieldName: "richTextCol", type: 'richText', wrapText: true, editable: true,
    cellAttributes: {
        class: 'slds-theme_alert-texture'
        } }
];

@track tableData = [
    // { id: 1, textCol: "Text", numberCol: 8, richTextCol: '<h3>Rich Text</h3>'}
    { id: 1, textCol: "Text", numberCol: 8, richTextCol: 'Rich Text'}
];
```

Comment: Please add the code of your datatable (markup+javascript) and all relevant other code to your question. It will facilitate answering!

Comment: @FelixvanHove thanks just added hopefully adds more context!

Comment: Could you add this as text instead of pictures? (We are software developers, not designers or photographers! ;-) ) Code as text facilitates copy-paste for anyone who wants to check out your code and answer. It also enables search engines to index keywords. Finally it helps to read on mobile devices and makes code presentation on a website like this more consistent.

Comment: @FelixvanHove makes sense lol, I think this should do it now.